# .NET Regex - block '%'

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to prevent users entering '%' or multiple '%'s in to a HTML form in .NET program. Tried pattern `(?!.%*)` but it's not working.  Regex should allow '%' in the string but should throw an error when only '%' are used.

Comment: % - invalid,  %% - invalid, fsd%lkf - Valid, %fslk valid

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a regex expert but this seems to be working for me:

```
bool IsInputValid(string input)
{
    return !Regex.IsMatch(input,"^[%]+$");
}
```

And an example:

```
Debug.WriteLine(IsInputValid("%")); // False
Debug.WriteLine(IsInputValid("%%")); // False
Debug.WriteLine(IsInputValid("fsd%lkf")); // True
Debug.WriteLine(IsInputValid("%fslk")); // True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your inputs. I have tried several combinations from your answers finally came up with ([^%])(.*)$
It came pretty close (still %%xxx is marked as invalid).
But this works for me now.